# Scanf decimal numbers inside escaped bracket literals

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

I want to read decimal numbers from the stdin, surrounded by square brackets. Currently, I'm using `scanf()` with the format specifier `%d`. If the conversion failed, I'm exiting the program with an error code 1.

```
int result = scanf(" [ %d ] ", &num);
if (result != 1)
  return 1;
```

For example this input doesn't trigger the conversion fail:
`[ 123`

I if understand it correctly `scanf()` is interpreting square brackets `[]` as a "set" of characters? Is there a way to tell `scanf()` to interpret square brackets `[]` literally? Or a simple (but fully functioning) workaround?

Comment: No, you're not accessing the "set" functionality here.  Your problem is that `scanf` has no way to tell you it failed to match the final closing bracket.  Its return value only tells you how many of the `%` format specifiers successfully matched.

Comment: There are ways around this (you could use `%c` to fetch the final `]`, and use an extra `if` statement to make sure you got it), but arguably, what you're trying to do is simply beyond `scanf`'s (eternally limited) capabilities, and you might want to pursue a completely different, non-`scanf`-based approach.

Comment: @SteveSummit This is a great workaround. Thank you.

Comment: @SteveSummit Can you please provide your comment as an answer. I think it may be useful for others.

Comment: @kaylum Well, see, I have a pretty big vendetta *against* scanf; I have a mission to convince everyone to not use it at all, or (maybe) to use it only for the simplest things until they can wean themselves off of it.  That's why I buried my suggestion inside a parenthetical in a comment, as opposed to a full-fledged answer.  Feel free to make your own answer out of my suggestion if you want to, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use *scanf*. Use *fgets*, check the square brackets yourself, and use *strtol* to convert the number. You should use *endptr* to check for extra closing characters, which could be a useful way of finding the closing ].